# Briefly, BIOS vs DOS

Tags: operating-system, dos, bios

What's the main difference between Basic Input Output System [**BIOS**] and Disk Operating System [**DOS**]?

Both are applications that have interrupts, I'm really very confused!

Before down-voting me, I google that question and didn't find an answer, so please answer me as I really care about learning the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complete beginner DOS is an operating system (Like windows, linux etc) but was used earlier (Use command prompt in your windows computer you'll get idea how it was used). It is installed on harddisk and runs after the system boots up.

But, when we power on the PC we need some firmware to check if RAM, Hard disk and all other component are in place, working and this piece of firmware needs to sit on your ROM rather then hard disk so that in case you've accidently removed hard disk, this self test will still be performed.

So in short => DOS = Operating system
BIOS => The self test your computer performs before loading the actually operating system ( DOS/ Windows etc)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful "BIOS loads DOS".

Comment: Yup, actually BIOS is the test your PC performs, then it loads DOS/Windows whats operating system you're having. DOS is outdated (although few fans and some organisations still use it probably) and was used before windows 95. But BIOS on the other hand is used to check the system state on power on to see if all components are working normally, even windows 7.

Comment: then there's no PC without bios but there's without dos one, true ?

Comment: Yup absolutely correct (excluding some geek's or researcher's computers who cannot afford the few second delays at boot).

Comment: This is misleading; BIOS is not the test, it's actually used to perform vital services for many operating systems. Its name (basic input/output system) reflects this; DOS, for instance, *uses* the BIOS in order to do many tasks, including hard-disk access, writing to the screen, etc. You don't just get a computer for "researchers" without BIOS; you need something to bootstrap the OS.

Comment: Exactly, the aforementioned "test" is in fact the POST (Power-On Self-Test) stage.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that Wikipedia can't tell you: [DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) and [BIOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS)...

Comment: I got them before asking, I didn't really know the major difference!